# How to match data in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset which contain three variables `var1`, `var2`, and `Price`. `Price` is the price of `var2`. `var1` is a subsample of of `Var2`. Now, I want to find the price of each product in `var1` by matching the name of `Var1` with `Var2`.
The data looks like this. Can anyone help me solve this out please. Many thanks

```
Var1    Var2    Price
apple           ?
        apple   2
banana          ?
        banana  2.1
apple           ?
orange          ?
        orange  4
banana          ?
        yoghurt 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this through SQL by merging your prices onto your dataset by var1/var2:

```
proc sql ;
create table output as
    select a.var1, a.var2, b.price
    from input a
    left join (select distinct var2, price
      from input 
      where not missing(var2)) as b
    on (a.var1=b.var2
    or a.var2=b.var2)
;quit ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use hash table.

```
 data want;
   if 0 then set have(keep=var2 price where=(not missing(var2)));
   if _n_=1 then do;
      declare hash h (dataset:'have1(keep=var2 price where=(not missing(var2)))');
      h.definekey('var2');
      h.definedata('price');
      h.definedone();
      call missing(var2,price);
    end;
    set have;
    rc=h.find(key:var1);
    drop rc;
    run;
```